# Associação right join do access não mostra todos os registros

Tags: microsoft-access

Depois que fiz a associação entre as tabelas o sistema mostra apenas os registros associados entre as duas tabelas: **TBPaciente** e **TBMotivo**.

```
SELECT TBPaciente.*, TBMotivo.* FROM TBMotivo RIGHT JOIN TBPaciente 
   ON TBMotivo.ID_MOTIVO = TBPaciente.ID_MOTIVO;
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que mostre todos os **6 Mil registros** da tabela **TBPaciente**, o que está errado ?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na imagem acima **o sistema mostra apenas 5 registros** que é os registros que estão associados, preciso que mostre todos 6 mil registros.

Comment: Você está usando a consulta para o cadastro?

Comment: Sim, estou usando para cadastro.

Comment: Faz um formulário direto e acrescente a relação depois, assim funciona